# Преобразовать формат даты

Tags: java, дата

Приходит JSON вот с такой датой:

```
2019-06-10T23%3A59%3A59%2B03%3A00
```

Подскажите как привести ее в человеческий вид? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/wsTA1l

```
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.net.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("2019-06-10T23%3A59%3A59%2B03%3A00", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
  }
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138183/4928642